# Употребление слова "контесса"

Tags: переводы

Не смог найти ничего определённого на этот счёт. Можно ли употреблять в русском языке, либо мы обязаны переводить как "графиня"? И если переводить как "контесса" можно, то имеем ли мы право, используя это слово, называть другого её родственника "графом" или же должны тогда на что-то, по аналогии с контессой, заменить этот титул?

Answer (score 2):

Ну тут наверное надо ещё и учитывать статус этого понятия, это вроде и не часть фамилии, и это не совсем должность, но тоже обладает рядом таких свойств, как должностные права и обязанности, и вот их конт может быть наделён чуть другими правами и обязанностями, нежели наш граф, и в таком случае это совершенно другой социальный статус. Значит, если речь идёт о лице иностранного государства и титуле, то надо так и называть, чтоб случайно не унизить его титул.

Answer (score 1):

Считаю, что слова "граф", "графиня" являются наиболее приемлемыми в русском языке для перевода соответствующих слов, имеющихся во французском языке:
le comte - граф;
la comtesse - графиня (контесса?)
Если кто-то всё-таки применил слово "контесса" (французское произношение " контэсс"),то сомневаюсь, что было бы уместным использовать и его "мужской" французский вариант "конт" - граф. Могу с уверенностью сказать, что в этом случае никто бы даже не понял значения этого слова. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, уместно говорить эти слова в русском переводе: граф - графиня.
Но!
le prince - принц
lа princesse - принцесса

Думаю, русский "женский вариант" вполне допустим, что нельзя сказать о "мужском варианте". Любой автор может на свое усмотрение употребить то или иное иностранное слово, если его применение имеет лишь одно значение.  Красивое слово "контесса"!  Но не менее "элегантен" его русский перевод "графиня"!

Comment:  prince еще можно перевести как "князь", а вот "виконт", "виконтесса" тут не знаю других вариантов. Слова "контесса" в русском языке нет. Не понимаю автора вопроса - в чем причина его колебаний?

Comment:  @Тина как это нет, если оно упоминается в переводе произведения Оскара Уайльда "Идеальный муж",а так к же в переводе "Вальпургиевой ночи" Майрика?

Comment: В чьем переводе? Мало ли что себе позволяют переводчики! Они не только новые слова придумывают, но и старые порой употребляют как-то не по-русски.

Answer (score 0):

Его Величество Русский Язык
Титул на Руси - граф и графиня; передаётся через первой степени (родители - дети) кровное родство. При остальных уровнях родства нужно знание. См. о Безухове в "Войне и мире".